# How to get the date from date picker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I implemented date picker using this library.
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

But the date is not properly fetched from the input field.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

I have used `$dob = $_POST['dob'];` but that input field doesn't return any value.

### HTML CODE

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
<div class="input-group date" id="dp3" data-date-viewMode="years" data-date="select a value" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input name="date" type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default add-on" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="sub btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### PHP CODE

```
$date=$_POST['date'];
```

Comment: Its in a standard html input. Retrieve it however you retrieve normal form values, probably by `$_POST['name'];`

Comment: I used php code $_POST['name']; but no value is made in that variable. I think it uses some kind of javascript. plz help

Comment: well, substitute name for whatever you named the input in your markup - i have no idea what that is because you havent posted any code

Comment: Now i have posted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Code

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<div class="well">
              <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" name="dob" value="" readonly="">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
              </div>
          </div>
<input type="submit" value="show">
</form>
```

PHP Code in the form action.php

```
<?php
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
?>
```

use this $dob variable in your database query.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the markup for the `<form...` as well, as its not obvious if the OP is even using a form.

Comment: I have used this code early. The input field with datepicker doesn't returning any value on submit!

Comment: check the url after submitting form. is "action.php" there ?

Comment: Yes! datepicker and other form elements are in home page. im using a php page called new.php for action of the from. The database query are made in new.php. I have successfully registered all the values in the database except the date picker. I have used ` $dob = $_POST['dob']; ` but there is no value in that field when submitted.

Then i made same page for action. But no use!

Comment: use echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';
and check whats coming in dob index of $_POST array.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked. check these:

[Pass selected date values from datepicker to php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556659/pass-selected-date-values-from-datepicker-to-php)

[Getting selected date from calendar date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956413/getting-selected-date-from-calendar-date-picker)

[How to get date with datepicker and pass via GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204313/how-to-get-date-with-datepicker-and-pass-via-get)

You will find your answer there. You acn check this code as well:

```
   <html>
  <head>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
                 $("#date").datepicker();
           });
   </script>
     </head>

   <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
               Date of Birth : <input type="text" name="date" id="date"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

tell me if you want something other than this.You can store date in DB also by using Date type of column.

Answer (score 0):

For first input box you can use this `$(dp1).val()`

Answer (score 0):

You must have assigned an id to the Input field right? Say the id is **dp1** (as it is in the link provided by you). Then you can get the date using the following jquery command:

> $('#dp1').val()

You can try it in the link shared by you. Just type the command in the console. Change the date of the first datepicker and retry. For the value of the second datepicker, just change he id to that of the second field..

Comment: Thanks. Im using datepicker my home page, But i'm using php action in another page(new.php). can you tell me how to pass a value to the php action page ?

Comment: Is the datepicker a part of the form which the user submits? And is "new.php" the action for the form?

Comment: Yes! datepicker and other form elements are in home page. im using a php page called new.php for action of the from. The database query are made in new.php. I have successfully registered all the values in the database except the date picker.  I have used ` $dob = $_POST['dob']; ` but there is no value in that field when submitted.